# When installing react-Facebook-login, I get "Could not resolve dependency"

Tags: reactjs

```
ERR! code ERESOLVE
ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-facebook-login@4.1.1
ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My website login function work properly, but I don't know how to install react-Facebook-login library in my project. When I try to install it above error render, I was not able to figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: What command are you using to install this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `react-facebook-login@4.1.1` requires `react@^16.0.0` as its peer dependency, but you have `react@18.2.0` installed in your project. That's why you got the warning when using npm v7, see [npm v7 Series - Beta Release! And: SemVer-Major Changes in npm v7](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major).

```bash
$ npm view react-facebook-login@4.1.1 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.0.0' }
```

Option 1.

Downgrade the react from `18.2.0` to `^16.0.0`, then install `react-facebook-login` again.

Option 2. mentioned at this [issues#320](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/320)

`npm install react-facebook-login -S --force` or `npm install react-facebook-login -S --legacy-peer-deps`

There may be version incompatibility issues by using this way.